# MVC Authentication - Easiest Way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have looked at ASP.NET Identity and it looks really complex and difficult to follow. Basically what I want to know is the easiest way to authorize a user on login so the [Authorize] data annotation will allow them through.

Comment: Take a look at this link. It explains forms authentication. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Comment: Try to follow this how-to: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2014/10/aspnet-mvc-forms-authentication-in-eight-easy-steps.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Install the following NuGet packages

- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

Inside App_Start folder, add a AuthConfig that look like this:

```
public static class AuthConfig
{
    public const string DefaultAuthType = "DefaultAppCookie"; //example
    public const string LoginPath = "System/SignIn"; //example

    public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthType,
            LoginPath = new PathString(LoginPath)
        });
    }
}
```

In the root path of the project, add a Startup.cs that look like this

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourPorject.Startup))]
namespace YourPorject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AuthConfig.ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }

}
```

To authenticate an user (usually inside a Login Action):

```
//user = the user that is loggin on, retrieved from database 
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                //some other claims
            };

ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthConfig.DefaultAuthType);
IAuthenticationManager authManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

You need to add a ClaimTypes.Role to authorize specific roles.

Comment: Thanks for your post. One quick question, what does DefaultAuthType entail? Thanks

Comment: It is just a const string to be used in the Login Action... because the name of the authentication type used in ClaimsIdentity object must match with the AuthConfig

Comment: It was extremely difficult to find a complete example for claims and roles being persisted without asp.net identity. Thank you.