# form authentication redirect page showing 401 error Mvc4 Empty Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, form-authentication

I had tried
 - RedirectToAction
 - Redirect
 - Url.Action

I'm creating an application form authentication using mvc4 empty project.

Here is code for login

```
[HttpPost]

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(UserModel user, string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        string EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
        string Password = user.Password;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) && EmailAddress == "admin@gmail.com" && Password == "admin123")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(EmailAddress, true); 
            // Result = new { Status = "Success" };
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(EmailAddress, true);
            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index","Home"));

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // logging
        throw;
    }
}

}
```

**My FilterConfig**

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }
    }
```

I'm new to this section. I'm wondering why it is happening?

Screenshot of response after redirection to home page.

[image: Error Page on redirect action]

Comment: It seems that you are using the old forms authentication, while your application uses owin authentication. How is the authorize attribute configured?

Comment: I assume you are attempting to login as admin@gmail and using the specified password, correct?

Comment: @FabioLuz what is new way? what is owin authentication? Authrorize i got from `using System.Web.Security;`

Comment: @stephen.vakil that is not an issue. How can i resolve this?

Comment: @KaushikKishore Take a look at your solution, look for the file AuthConfig.cs (inside App_Start folder) and Startup.cs inside root folder. Did you find these files? if yes, post them in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Authorization is not working because you are trying to use the old FormsAuthentication method, while you are using the new `AuthorizeAttribute` that uses OWIN authentication.

Follow this question [MVC Authentication - Easiest Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095889/mvc-authentication-easiest-way/32096289#32096289). It should solve your problem.

Comment: Where I'll add code below this line
`To authenticate an user (usually inside a Login Action):`

Comment: In the same place your are using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(EmailAddress, true);`. In your case, inside Index Action. (You have to remove the 2 FormsAuthentication Line)