# .aspxauth is created, but ASP.NET MVC controller with Authorize attribute doesn't recognize it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5.1 project and I'm trying to get Forms Authentication to work with System.Web.Security. The .ASPXAUTH cookie is being created successfully, but the Authorize attribute on the Home Controller is ignoring it.

BTW, this application is currently in development, so I'm not hitting a database yet.

Any ideas why?

Comment: what is the full assembly name of [Authorize]?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute - v5.2.2.  This is the default attribute, I didn't create something custom, if that's what you are wondering.

Comment: I'm not sure why [Authorize] is not working, but I believe the problem is the FormsAuthentication class from System.Web.Security. FormsAuthentication is an old way to handle authentication. Try to use OWIN, it works better. See an example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095889/mvc-authentication-easiest-way