# Easiest way to set up/handle authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC application with database that already has users and roles

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I have a complete ASP.NET Core MVC application and a database that has users and roles already added. User registration is handled externally and I just need to provide authentication and authorization to the ASP.NET Core MVC app I am building for users already in the database.

What's the best way to do that?

I've tried setting up Identity and connecting it to the user/role database via Entity Framework, but it seems like overkill and the setup has been overwhelming. Any recommendations on the simplest way accomplish this?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095889/mvc-authentication-easiest-way), but a lot of it doesn't seem to apply to ASP.NET Core MVC ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> need to provide authentication and authorization to the ASP.NET Core MVC app I am building for users already in the database

As you mentioned, you already have `users` and `roles` related tables with records in your database, to implement/integrate authentication functionality in your ASP.NET Core MVC app, you can try to use cookie-based authentication provider without ASP.NET Core Identity.

*Service configuration for authentication*

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
    //...
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
    options.Cookie.Name = "authcookie";
});
```

*Action method `Login`*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
    if (LoginUser(loginModel.Username, loginModel.Password))
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginModel.Username)
    };

        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

        //Just redirect to our index after logging in. 
        return Redirect("/");
    }
    return View();
}

    private bool LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {
        //code logic here 
        //check record from your database

        //... 
        return true;
    }
```

[This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with sample explained about implement cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity, you can refer to it.